# What is the difference between "opacity" and "filter: opacity()"

Tags: css, transparency, opacity

Most of us know the simple `opacity` CSS rule, but recently I stumbled upon `filter` which can have `opacity(amount)` as it value - among other things. But what exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`filter` in CSS had some different runs, namely for FireFox and MSIE.

---

In MSIE 5.5 on through 7, [`filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), also known as [`Alpha Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), actually makes use of MSIE's [DX Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532849%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). However, in order to be more CSS2.1 compliant, in IE8 MS introduced [`-ms-filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to *replace* [`filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The syntax is different in that the **value** of [`-ms-filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must be encased in *quotes*. Eventually, IE9 brought deprecation to this method and as of IE10, it is no longer used.

---

Another interesting note here, if you're wanting full compatibility for older IE, then you must make sure use of [`filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`-ms-filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must be very specific. For example, the following does not work in IE8 running IE7 compat mode:

```
element {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

[`-ms-filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) **must** come before [`filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to get more out of older IE compatibility.Like so:

```
element {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

---

FireFox made use of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) as an experiment gone awry. I believe the original idea was to mock what IE was doing in using the Direct X engine. There was even a browser specific version, as there was for most browsers at one time. Eventually, HTML5/CSS3 announced use of the `filter` namespace and it now has a new purpose.

---

As of CSS3, [`filter`](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) now has a whole new meaning! Firefox docs stay open as if they plan to expand on this, though I've yet to see it (however they do crash JS if your CSS is not to its liking now!). Webkit (which will probably become standard in next update to CSS3) has started to implement [`filter`](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) to the point you can almost "*photoshop*" images for your site!

Since filter is changing so much, `opacity` would be the *preferred* method to use, however, as you can see, to be completely cross-browser compatible means being very thorough.

---

Browser specific alternates:

- -webkit-filter: filter(value);
- -moz-filter: filter(value);
- -o-filter: filter(value);
- -ms-filter: "progid:DXCLASS.Object.Attr(value)";

---

### See Also:

- [What's compatible with `opacity`?](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity)
- [What's compatible with the newer `filter`?](http://caniuse.com/css-filters)

  - *keep in mind, not the same as Older IE's filter*

Comment: I know, this post is dead, but, why is this answere is marked as correct? you only discribe about filter and -ms-filter (and the other browser specific filters). you didn't answere the question: what's the difference between using e.g. `opacity:0.2` and `filter:opactity(20%)`?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger " ... filter is changing so much, opacity would be the preferred method to use  ... " Because OP got exactly what s/he wanted out of it.

Comment: So to conclude... there is no reason to use `filter` over `opacity` except for IE < 6 compatibility (or IE < 9, as support is "partial" in between)  ?

Comment: @AdrienK Yeah pretty much. `filter` is really only for IE 5-7, and `-ms-filter-` is good till 9. For everything else, just use `opacity`. I'd encourage more "Your browser is not compat. Please upg" type pages for anything IE<=9

Answer (score 10):

> **filter: opacity()** is similar to the more established **opacity** property; the *difference* is that with **filter: opacity()**, some browsers provide
>   hardware acceleration for better performance. Negative values are not
>   allowed.
>
> **filter: opacity()** applies transparency.
>   A value of 0% is completely transparent. A value of 100% leaves the
>   input unchanged. Values between 0% and 100% are linear multipliers on
>   the effect. This is equivalent to multiplying the input image samples
>   by amount. If the “amount” parameter is missing, a value of 100% is
>   used.

Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

```css
/*
* -----------
* filter: opacity([ <number> or <percentage> ])
* -----------
*/

.filter-opacity {
  filter: opacity(0.3);
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
}

/*
* -----------
* standard opacity
* -----------
*/

.just-opacity {
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-opacity">
  filter-opacity
</div>

<div class="just-opacity">
  just-opacity
</div>
```

Comment: typo? u comparing `filter: opacity()` and `filter: opacity()`

Comment: @Ivan not sure what you mean, I am comparing `filter: opacity()` with the `opacity` css property.

Comment: Official source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/opacity mentioned also on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57370045/134824

Answer (score 4):

I've found some difference between them both, especially in the Chrome browser.
If we set the CSS `opacity` property to an `iframe` tag, then we'll not be able to click any links inside this frame (I guess, it's a protection from `clickjacking` attack) while `filter: opacity(0)` allows us to click any links. I don't know, maybe it's an omission from Chrome developers' side.