# CSS3: opacity vs filter opacity?

Tags: css, opacity

I was playing with the CSS3 filter functions (blur, contrast, invert, etc.), and noticed there is an `opacity` function:

```
filter: opacity(0.5);
-webkit-filter: opacity(0.5);
-moz-filter: opacity(0.5);
```

While we already have:

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

If we apply both of them for a HTML element, it seems like it's getting double effect!

Now that makes me wonder, is there any difference?

**EDIT:**

I'm not asking about the old IE `filter: alpha(opacity=50)` as that is Microsoft's implementation. I'm asking about the CSS3 `filter` vs CSS3 `opacity`?

Comment: There is a similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310219/what-is-the-difference-between-opacity-and-filter-opacity).

Comment: @JimmyKo Thanks for pointing that post. The selected answer in that post doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: So are you asking for the difference of implementation between two properties? As w3c only provide the specification but not restricted the implementation. It is quite difficult to answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you @JoeRohney to point out @ArmanNisch's answer, I'm posting this answer as future reference to anyone looking for an answer from official source.

Based on [official source (Mozilla documentations) about **filter: opacity(value)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/opacity):

> Note: This function is similar to the more established `opacity`
>   property. **The difference is that with filters, some browsers provide
>   hardware acceleration for better performance.**

Answer (score 5):

@bram-vanroy posted this same question already, basically. I thought [this was the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310219/what-is-the-difference-between-opacity-and-filter-opacity#53299274).

> **filter: opacity()** is similar to the more established **opacity** property;
>   the difference is that with **filter: opacity()**, some browsers provide
>   hardware acceleration for better performance. Negative values are not
>   allowed.
>
> **filter: opacity()** applies transparency. A value of 0% is completely
>   transparent. A value of 100% leaves the input unchanged. Values
>   between 0% and 100% are linear multipliers on the effect. This is
>   equivalent to multiplying the input image samples by amount. If the
>   “amount” parameter is missing, a value of 100% is used.